# NSCharacterSet for HTML characters? iPhone sdk web parsing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-services

I am parsing data from an rss. My problem is that the xmlparser dosn't parse properly. it only parses data partly. So to explain my situation a bit better I will give you and example. So say suppose there is a speical charecter in a title (parsing the titles)

like

```
"This is a test"
```

and in rss it is written like this

```
<title>&#8220;This is a test&#8220;</title>
```

and when i try to parse the data I just get 
a

```
 "
```

why is doing this and How can i fix it here is some code

```
 -(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{

 currentNodeContent = [string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`parser:foundCharacters:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/NSXMLParserDelegate) may be called several times with characters for the same element. You need to create a mutable string and append the characters until `parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:` is called for the associated element. The xml decoding should be automatic and that is why you were just getting the " which was just the last character(`&#8220;`) in your node.

> The parser object may send the delegate several
>   parser:foundCharacters: messages to report the characters of an
>   element. Because string may be only part of the total character
>   content for the current element, you should append it to the current
>   accumulation of characters until the element changes.

Comment: Have a look at the section Parse an element value hand Parse the end of an element section here  http://wiki.cs.unh.edu/wiki/index.php/Parsing_XML_data_with_NSXMLParser